# Using R, how would I perform linear regression with error in one of the variables

Tags: r, regression, linear, measurement-error

I want to perform linear regression between two sets of data points. The dependent variable is an exact point measurement. However, the independent variable was obtained from the literature and has associated error **(mean and associated 95% CI)**,

e.g.

```
X (mean (95%))         Y 
82 (75-90)             360 
83 (77-90)             400 
98 (92-104)            500
254 (240-268)          2000
435 (425-446)          3500
312 (297-326)          2500
```

I would lake to perform a linear regression taking into account the error in the X variable. Within `R`, the `lm()` function handles the simple regression situation, but since I have the associated error, I would like to include that in the model.

Comment: Take a look at errors in variables regression. Wayne Fuller has a book on the subject.  It is also referred to as Deming regression.

Comment: Fuller's book is  Measurement Error Models (1987) Wiley.  A short bio with additional information is in Wikipedia titled "Wayne Fuller".

Comment: Here's a thought: as confidence interval for a value becomes too wide, one wouldn't want to give too much weight to such observations. My idea being, define a sample-weight which is a function of the confidence interval. It could be function of absolute or % value of the possible error in X. Now feed that to your linear regression model. Thus, model training would put more effort to minimise errors where you are more confident about the X value.

Comment: What is "an exact point measurement"? Are you saying you assume no error in y? The numbers in your example certainly look suspicious and if that is really your data you should probably just do (possibly weighted) OLS of `x ~ y` and inverse predict if needed.

Comment: @Roland for this particular analysis I am assuming no error in y. I was actually planning on analyzing 1000s of samples from a posterior distribution (y values will be different every time), calculate the regression for each. The Y values in this example are just place holders.

Comment: There is a package called `deming`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [eivtools](https://github.com/jrlockwood/eivtools) package. It is not on CRAN so you will have to use the `devtools` package as follows.

`devtools::install_github("jrlockwood/eivtools")`

Also look over the articles included in the package documentation. NOTE: this seems to be a developing package, so you must be cautious with the results. I will say that I played around with a simple simulation with this package and it did recover the population parameters quite well.

Here is a more recent references than the great Fuller book mentioned in the comments:

Carroll, R., Ruppert, D., Stefanski, L., & Crainiceanu, C. (2006). Measurement error in non-
linear models: A modern perspective (2nd ed.). London, England: Chapman and Hall.