# Linear regression on data with associated errors in the x and y direction

Tags: regression, linear, error, error-propagation

I have experimental data that I need to linearise in the form $\ln(b/x)$ vs. $x$, where $x$ is an experimentally-derived quantity and the value of $x$ is dependent on $b$ (which varies).

$x$ has some measurement error associated with it ($b$ does not). I need the value and the uncertainty in the $y$-intercept. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about doing this, considering there are errors in both $y$ and $x$ direction, but they are obviously associated?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question.  Are you fitting a regression model?

It seems like it is a type of [Errors in variables model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models).

[This question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256839/using-r-how-would-i-perform-linear-regression-with-error-in-one-of-the-variable) might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to fit a linear regression model that can account for the error in both x and y and that gives me an error on the y-intercept.

Comment: OK. Then you want to fit an errors in variables model.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a more detailed look at Deming regression (one of the suggested models), but one of the model's assumptions is that errors in y and x are independent, which is not the case in my problem. I'm not sure how to overcome this issue.